# Unable to proceed through OAuth2.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0

I have generated tokens and code and everything and i am able to login and authorize the user but somehow I am getting error. Two error has been spotted.

First One

```
(
    [error] => invalid_grant
    [error_description] => Authorization code doesn't exist or is invalid for the client
)
```

Sometimes authorization code is not generating so I am getting above error. And sometimes when I am able to generate auth_code I am getting below error

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"The access token provided is invalid"}
```

I am developer of the site abcd.com and now I have a platform where I need to develop my abcd.com for that platform. To implement login I have to use OAuth2.0 and this is the requirement of the platform. I have read a lot of documents on OAuth2.0 and build the app. I am using codeigniter though.

**server.php**

```
$dsn      = 'mysql:dbname=my_oauth2_db;host=localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

// error reporting (this is a demo, after all!)
ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Autoloading (composer is preferred, but for this example let's just do this)
require_once('oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2/Autoloader.php');
OAuth2\Autoloader::register();

// $dsn is the Data Source Name for your database, for exmaple "mysql:dbname=my_oauth2_db;host=localhost"
$storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

// Pass a storage object or array of storage objects to the OAuth2 server class
$server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);

// Add the "Client Credentials" grant type (it is the simplest of the grant types)
$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));

// Add the "Authorization Code" grant type (this is where the oauth magic happens)
$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\AuthorizationCode($storage));

$scope = new OAuth2\Scope(array(
  'supported_scopes' => array('email')
));
$server->setScopeUtil($scope);
```

Here is my **authorize.php**

```
require_once __DIR__.'/server.php';
$request = OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals();

$client_id      = $request->query['client_id'];
$response = new OAuth2\Response();

if (!$server->validateAuthorizeRequest($request, $response)) {
    $response->send();
    die;
}
if (empty($_POST)) {
  exit('<form method="post">
                  <label>Do You Authorize '.$client_id.'?</label><br />
                  <input class="yes_authorize" type="submit" name="authorized" value="Yes">
                  <input class="no_authorize" type="submit" name="authorized" value="No">
                </form>');
}

$is_authorized = ($_POST['authorized'] === 'Yes');
$server->handleAuthorizeRequest($request, $response, $is_authorized);
if ($is_authorized) {

  $code = substr($response->getHttpHeader('Location'), strpos($response->getHttpHeader('Location'), 'code=')+5, 40);
  $client_secret        = $_GET['state'];
  $token_value          = shell_exec("curl -u CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET https://abcd.com/api/token.php -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=$code'");

  $token        = json_decode($token_value);
  $access_token = $token->access_token;
  $expires_in   = $token->expires_in;
  $state        = $_GET['state'];

  $resource_result = shell_exec("curl https://abcd.com/api/resource.php -d 'access_token=$code'");

  $redirect_url = $_GET['redirecturi']."?code=$access_token&state=".$_GET['state'];
  exit(header("location: $redirect_url"));
}
$response->send();
```

**resource.php**

```
require_once __DIR__.'/server.php';
if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())) {
    $server->getResponse()->send();
    die;
}
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'You accessed my APIs!'));
```

**token.php**

```
require_once __DIR__.'/server.php';

$server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

If you see authorize.php, After generating access_token through token.php, If I pass that to resource.php, I am getting second error. AND I have passed auth_code as well as access_token both to my redirect url, but I am getting not able to get through.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: No.. i didn't get any solution yet.